# prestashop backoffice login Issue

Tags: prestashop

I have problem. I can't login into backoffice.

I contacted with hosting provider and they said it's not problem from their side.

Any fix for it?

Comment: Prestashop version?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution my side
its issue with third party module
when I disable the Merchant Expertise module its work fine for me

Comment: Can you give the exact name of the module folder?

Comment: I think it is 'gamification'

Comment: Right issue is gamification module But when you go to admin side it displayed name is  "Merchant Expertise"

Comment: So the solution was to increase server timeout limits and disable it from the backoffice?

Comment: @GonzaloFaus I just figured that out myself too! It is absolutely `gamification`. A PrestaShop native module.

Comment: Yes, increase server timeout limits and disable it from the back office

Comment: you can run the uninstall script adding `index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=X&uninstall=gamification&tab_module=others&module_name=gamification&anchor=Gamification` and understanding the risks

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop is having problems at the moment relative to `addons.prestashop.com` service.

As mentioned by VBK you should disable `gamification` module if installed. To do so, you can login on your FTP and rename `/modules/gamification` to `/modules/gamification_disable`.

You should then be able to log on your Backoffice.

---

Due to the addons service inaccessibility, you might find your backoffice to be slower than usual.

For Prestashop versions < 1.7:
In file `/classes/Tools.php`
For Prestashop versions > 1.7:
In file `/src/Adapter/Addons/AddonsDataProvider.php`

Find the line `protected static $is_addons_up = true;` that you replace with `protected static $is_addons_up = false;`

This will prevent your website from trying to access `addons.prestashop.com` service.

Answer (score 0):

Please ***clear your browsers cache*** and then try to login again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and fastest way via FTP remove "/gamification" directory from /modules

Comment: This option worked.
Remove the gamification folder from ```public_html/yourdomain/modules```